# Can command blocks look for a block in an area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can a command block look for a block in an area and not a specific pattern of this block but weither its there or not?
I whould assume that you could use /testforblocks for this but I couldent figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the /fill command to detect whether a certain block is present.

Assuming you can create a redstone clock to suit your needs, attach a command block to it that has the command `/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> sponge 0 replace <block>`. (Fill in the coordinates with the coordinates you need, and fill in  with the type of block you're testing for.) You can take a comparator output from that command block to know whether the block was present. You also need to put a command block that's activated IMMEDIATELY after that that has the command `/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> 0 replace sponge`. This will reset the sponges that were created by the previous command block to be .

Notice I used sponge as the temporary block. If there are other sponges in the area that you're testing, you will want to pick a different block to use as a temporary block (one that's not in the selected area).

I hope this helped.

Comment: Why don't you just replace <block> with itself?! That gives the same comparator output